# Projecting Shapefile from WGS to Web Mercator changes output Field Type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.6, here-maps

Using ArcGIS 10.6 I am trying to project a shapefile data from Here street data-set in `GCS WGS 1984` to `WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere`. While the original data has an attribute like

[image]

it changes the `POINT_NUM` and `Z_LEVEL` data type from `Short Integer` to `Long Integer`

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

To try and reproduce your problem, using the same two coordinate systems as you on some test data that I created, I ran the test code below:

```
import arcpy
srWGS84 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
srWebMerc = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)")
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/Temp/testWGS84.shp",
                               "0 0","0 1","1","1","1","1",
                               "","NO_LABELS","DEFAULT","POLYGON")
arcpy.DefineProjection_management("C:/Temp/testWGS84.shp",srWGS84)
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/Temp/testWGS84.shp","POINT_NUM",
                          "SHORT","","","","","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","")
arcpy.Project_management("C:/Temp/testWGS84.shp","C:/Temp/testWebMerc.shp",
                         srWebMerc,"",srWGS84,"NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE","","NO_VERTICAL")
```

The Short Integer field that I added remained as a Short Integer after running the Project.

Consequently, I am unable to reproduce what you are describing.  If you cannot produce your unexpected result when running my test, I suggest that you investigate how the shapefile which you do see the unexpected result on was created.